# angular prevent user multiple submit

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

Sometimes user click the save button multiple times and it queues and submit a lot of request and multiple data are created.

How do we prevent it on the front-end that even user click the button multiple times only one request is submitted , anyone knows a clean implementation ? what are the techniques ?

Thanks.

#html code

```
 <ng-template #editButtons>
      <div class="flex" *ngIf="isEditing">
        <app-page-section-cards-btn
          [btnData]="pageSectionsOptions.btnData.cancel"
          (btnClickEvent)="cancelEdit()"></app-page-section-cards-btn>
        <app-page-section-cards-btn
          [btnData]="pageSectionsOptions.btnData.save"
          (btnClickEvent)="saveDeal()">
      </app-page-section-cards-btn>
      </div>
    </ng-template>
```

## ts code

```
saveDeal(){
    const payload = {
      "id": 0,
      "name": this.dealDispositionFormFields.dealName,
      "dealType": "Idle Buyout",
      "annualRentProposed": null,
      "annualRentCurrent": null,
      "firmTermRemaining": null,
      "firmTermAdded": null,
      "maxAvailableTerm": null,
      "status": null,
      "capitalContribution": null,
      "parentCloneId": null,
      "accountId": this.currentAccount.accountId,
      "transactionId": this.transactionData.id,
      "dealTypeValues": JSON.stringify(dealTypeValues)
    }
    this.createDispositionDeal(payload);

  }

    createDispositionDeal(payload:any) {
      this._dealService.createDeal(payload)
      .subscribe(
        res=>{
          this._notificationService.showSuccess('Deal was successfully created.');
          if(res.isSuccess){
            this.refreshDealDetailsPage(res.data);
          }  
        },
        err=>{
          console.log('Error creating deal')
        }
      )
    }
```

Comment: disable the button in `saveDeal` and _maybe_ reenable after request returns?

Comment: do you have ssample implementations ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there is a perfect solution using rxjs  **exhaustMap** but You can simply disable your button during the processing of your call and enable it again when the reponse comes

```
isLoading = false;

saveDeal() {
 this.isLoading = true;
 ...
}


createDispositionDeal(payload:any) {
  this._dealService.createDeal(payload)
  .subscribe(
    res=>{
      this.isLoading = false; // here
      ...
    },
    err=>{
      this.isLoading = false; // here
      ...
    }
  )
}
```

and add a new input to your component  **[disabled]="isLoading"**

```
 <app-page-section-cards-btn
      [disabled]="isLoading"
      [btnData]="pageSectionsOptions.btnData.save"
      (btnClickEvent)="saveDeal()">
  </app-page-section-cards-btn>
```

Comment: how do I disable the <app-page-section-cards-btn when this is a child component

Comment: you can create an @input disabled and get it's value in your child component

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/nBEfR9z this is my app-page-section-cards-btn component

Comment: if you add  an input with the name disabled so it comes [disabled]="disabled" inside your child component

Comment: Sir , do you have an exhaustMap implementation ?

Comment: https://www.tektutorialshub.com/angular/using-exhaustmap-in-angular/ read this, it's quick check the last use case where there is an implementation